# Know when user navigates to another screen

Tags: ios, swift, navigation

I want to know that when user navigates to another screen. If there is any change in navigation stack, It should notify me. To do that, I do not want to write any code in viewwillappear of any viewcontroller. I wish to write it once and thus I can observe that which screen is navigated.

Answer (score 1):

Consider writing a super `UIViewController` which all your `UIViewController`s inherit from. Then you just write the code in your super ViewController

Comment: Thanks Nikolaj it works but the thing actually which I want to do is  implementing this without changing anything in base view controller. Adding observer to navigation controller could work but I tried that one. When I navigate to another screen, nothing changes.

Comment: Although observers aren't 100% reliable, I think it should work. When you implemented it, what method did you post the observer in? Was it fired and not received?

Answer (score 0):

Sample code for @Nikolaj Nielsen answer:

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
    var identifier: String {
       return ""
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewWillAppear(animated)
       print("Appeared VC: \(identifier)")
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
       print("Disappeared VC: \(identifier)")
    }
}

class CustomViewController: BaseViewController {
   override var identifier: String {
      return "CustomViewController"
   }
}
```